# Docusign SOAP API InPerson signing with multiple recipients and OpenTrust

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I am using Docusign SOAP API for in person signing with multiple recipients. Everything was working fine until, I wanted to integrate OpenTrust Certificate in my authentication. And here is the contradiction:

- For the in person signing to work, the RoutingOrder of the recipients must be the same. Or else you will get the following soap error:
  **The token for an out of sequence recipient cannot be generated.**
- For the OpenTrust certificate to work, the RoutingOrder must be diffent. Or else you will get the following error:
  **When RequireSignerCertificate is specified, there must not be another recipient at the same routing order.**

If I can find a solution for the in person signing with multiple recipients and different routing orders, maybe it would solve the problem. Here is a my code:

```
    Map<string, Docusign_API__c> mcs = Docusign_API__c.getAll();  
    String accountId = mcs.get('accountId').Value__c;
    String userId = '[' + UserInfo.getUserEmail()  + ';' + UserInfo.getName() + ']' + mcs.get('userId').Value__c;
    String password = mcs.get('password').Value__c;
    String integratorsKey = mcs.get('integratorsKey').Value__c;
    String webServiceUrl = mcs.get('webServiceUrl').Value__c;
    string CarbonCopyEmail = mcs.get('bcc').Value__c;

    string RecordId = 'a0411000006Ijy1';

    string envelopeId = null;

    DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap dsApiSend = new DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap();
    dsApiSend.endpoint_x = webServiceUrl;

    //Set Authentication
    system.debug(userId);
    String auth = '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>'+ userId
        +'</Username><Password>' + password
        + '</Password><IntegratorKey>' + integratorsKey
        + '</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>';
    System.debug('Setting authentication to: ' + auth);

    dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
    dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('X-DocuSign-Authentication', auth);

    DocuSignAPI.Envelope envelope = new DocuSignAPI.Envelope();
    envelope.Subject    = 'Please Sign this Contract: ' + contract.ContractNumber;
    envelope.EmailBlurb = 'This is my new eSignature service, it allows me to get your signoff without having to fax, scan, retype, refile and wait forever';
    envelope.AccountId  = accountId;

    envelope.CustomFields = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfCustomField();
    envelope.CustomFields.CustomField = new DocuSignAPI.CustomField[1];

    DocuSignAPI.CustomField env_customfield = new DocuSignAPI.CustomField();
    env_customfield.Name = 'DSFSSourceObjectId';
    env_customfield.Show = 'false';
    env_customfield.Required = 'true';
    env_customfield.Value = RecordId +'~object__c';
    env_customfield.CustomFieldType = 'Text';
    env_customfield.ListItems = '';       
    envelope.CustomFields.CustomField[0] = env_customfield;                   

    // Document
    //Add Attachments
    list<Attachment> listAttachments = [SELECT Id, Name, Body FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :RecordId];

    envelope.Documents = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfDocument();     
    envelope.Documents.Document = new DocuSignAPI.Document[listAttachments.size()];

    integer attCounter = 0;
    for(Attachment att : listAttachments){           
        DocuSignAPI.Document document2 = new DocuSignAPI.Document();
        document2.ID = attCounter;
        document2.pdfBytes = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(att.Body);
        document2.Name = att.Name;
        if(att.Name.contains('.')){
            document2.FileExtension = att.Name.split('\\.')[1];
        }

        envelope.Documents.Document[attCounter] = document2;
        attCounter++;
    }


    envelope.Recipients = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient();
    envelope.Recipients.Recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient[2];                       

    // Recipient 1
    DocuSignAPI.Recipient recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
    recipient.ID = 1;
    //recipient.RequireSignerCertificate = 'OpenTrust';
    recipient.Type_x = 'InPersonSigner';
    recipient.CaptiveInfo = new DocuSignAPI.RecipientCaptiveInfo();
    recipient.CaptiveInfo.ClientUserId = '1';                    
    recipient.RoleName = 'Signer 1';
    recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
    recipient.Email = 'recipient1@test.com';
    recipient.UserName = 'recipient1 test';  
    recipient.SignerName = 'recipient1 test';
    recipient.RequireIDLookup = false;                             
    envelope.Recipients.Recipient[0] = recipient;

    //Recipient2
    DocuSignAPI.Recipient recipient2 = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
    recipient2.ID = 2;
    //recipient2.RequireSignerCertificate = 'OpenTrust';       
    recipient2.Type_x = 'InPersonSigner';
    recipient2.Email = 'recipient1@test.com';
    recipient2.UserName = 'recipient1 test';                       
    recipient2.SignerName = 'Person 2';   
    recipient2.CaptiveInfo = new DocuSignAPI.RecipientCaptiveInfo();
    recipient2.CaptiveInfo.ClientUserId = '2';                
    recipient2.RoleName = 'Signer 2';
    recipient2.RoutingOrder = 2;       
    envelope.Recipients.Recipient[1] = recipient2;               

    envelope.Tabs = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTab();
    envelope.Tabs.Tab = new DocuSignAPI.Tab[2];

    // Tab - Apporteur
    DocuSignAPI.Tab tab1 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
    tab1.Type_x = 'SignHere';
    tab1.RecipientID = 1;
    tab1.DocumentID = 1;
    tab1.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
    tab1.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 's1';
    envelope.Tabs.Tab[0] = tab1;

    // Tab - Souscripteur
    DocuSignAPI.Tab tab2 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
    tab2.Type_x = 'SignHere';
    tab2.RecipientID = 2;
    tab2.DocumentID = 1;
    tab2.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
    tab2.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 's2';
    envelope.Tabs.Tab[1] = tab2;

    //I - Send Enveloppe
    DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus es = dsApiSend.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
    envelopeId = es.EnvelopeID;


    //II - Get Signing Toekn
    Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
    String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
    String guid = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);

    DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenAuthenticationAssertion assertion = new DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenAuthenticationAssertion();
    assertion.AssertionID = guid;
    assertion.AuthenticationInstant = DateTime.Now();
    assertion.AuthenticationMethod = 'Email';
    assertion.SecurityDomain = 'force.com';

    // Construct the URLs based on username
    DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs urls = new DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs();
    String urlBase = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+RecordId;
    urls.OnSigningComplete = urlBase + '?event=SignComplete&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
    urls.OnViewingComplete = urlBase + '?event=ViewComplete&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
    urls.OnCancel = urlBase + '?event=Cancel&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
    urls.OnDecline = urlBase + '?event=Decline&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
    urls.OnSessionTimeout = urlBase + '?event=Timeout&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
    urls.OnTTLExpired = urlBase + '?event=TTLExpired&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
    urls.OnIdCheckFailed = urlBase + '?event=IDCheck&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
    urls.OnAccessCodeFailed = urlBase + '?event=AccessCode&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
    urls.OnException = urlBase + '?event=Exception&uname=' + recipient.UserName;

    //Request second person token
    string RecipientToken  = dsApiSend.RequestRecipientToken(
        es.EnvelopeID,
        recipient.CaptiveInfo.ClientUserId,
        recipient.UserName,
        recipient.Email,
        assertion,
        urls);

    //Request second person token
    string RecipientToken2  = dsApiSend.RequestRecipientToken(
        es.EnvelopeID,
        recipient2.CaptiveInfo.ClientUserId,
        recipient2.UserName,
        recipient2.Email,
        assertion,
        urls);

    //Add the token of the second recipient in the Signing complete of the first
    //urls.OnSigningComplete = RecipientToken2;



    Pagereference tokenpage = new Pagereference(RecipientToken);
    return tokenpage.setRedirect(true);
```

Comment: Why don't you create envelope, generate recipient token for recipient #1 (which should work), when that person has done their portion, you generate recipient token for recipient #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core requirement (for OpenTrust signing) is that recipients must be set to sequential routing (e.g. RoutingOrder 1 and 2 for each recipient).  In sequential routing only one recipient is active at a time.  Once Signer 1 has signed they are marked as Complete and Signer 2 then becomes active.

A recipient can only sign while they are active.  This also applies to getting the recipient token.  You can only get a token for a signer who is active.

Note that In-Person signing does not actually require that recipients be in the same routing order.

The key to the solution is to request the second recipient token only after the first recipient has signed.  The first session's landing URL should point to a VF page - perhaps with the envelope ID as a parameter (or object ID for a record) for instance.  The controller for that VF page would then request the second signer's recipient token and either redirect to that URL or return it as the source URL in an IFrame.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I have another problem with OpenTrust but I was able to do an inperson signature with different routing orders.